# Download only the attachments from E-mails using JavaMail 1.4

Tags: java, email

I have the following code in my attempt to download the attachments from emails and I have the next error "Could not connect to the message store". Anyone, any help?

*ERROR

run:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:148)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at net.mail.EmailAttachmentReceiver.downloadEmailAttachments(EmailAttachmentReceiver.java:69)
    at net.mail.EmailAttachmentReceiver.main(EmailAttachmentReceiver.java:155)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:513)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:347)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:201)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:144)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 25 more
Could not connect to the message store
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

*CODE

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    package net.mail;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Address;
    import javax.mail.Folder;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
    import javax.mail.Part;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Store;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;


    public class EmailAttachmentReceiver {
    private String saveDirectory;

    /**
     * Sets the directory where attached files will be stored.
     * @param dir absolute path of the directory
     */
    public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
        this.saveDirectory = dir;
    }

    /**
     * Downloads new messages and saves attachments to disk if any.
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     */
    public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
            String userName, String password) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // server setting
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);

        // SSL setting
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
                String.valueOf(port));

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // connects to the message store
            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect(userName, password);

            // opens the inbox folder
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // fetches new messages from server
            Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                Message message = arrayMessages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                String attachFiles = "";

                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart)          multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                            part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }
                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                        || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();
                    }
                }

                // print out details of each message
                System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
                System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
                System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
                System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
                System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs this program with Gmail POP3 server
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String port = "995";
        String userName = "username";
        String password = "password";

        String saveDirectory = "D:/Attachment";

        EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
        receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
        receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use similar code and can connect with (see code examples in javamail-samples.zip, e.g. msgshow.java):

```
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
  props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(port));

  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

  Store store = null;
  store = session.getStore(protocol); // protocol is e.g. "pop3" or "imap"

  store.connect(host, port, user, password);
```